# Laravel Eloquent how to access distant relationship's data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a client table, a `client_contacts` table and a `contact_type` table. The client is a 1:m with `client_contacts`, and `client_contacts` is a 1:1 with `contact_type`.

The idea being that a client can have a primary contact, a billing contact, etc.

I'm trying to get both a given client, and it's contacts, along with the description of the contact's type. So in SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT c.*, cc.*, ct.contact_type_description
FROM client c
JOIN client_contacts cc ON c.id = cc.client_id
JOIN contact_types ct ON cc.contact_type_id = ct.id
WHERE c.id = 1
```

From what I'm reading, I need to use `HasManyThrough` for this?

Here's how I've set it up:

**Client Model**

```
class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'client_name',
        'address',
        'city',
        'state',
        'zip',
    ];

    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }

    public function contactTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ContactType::class, Contact::class);
    }
}
```

**Contact Model**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function contactType() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ContactType::class);
    }
}
```

**Contact Type Model**

```
class ContactType extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I'm just trying to dd() the data for now.

```
public function edit(Client $client)
{    
  $contacts = $client->contacts;
  $ct = $client->contactTypes();
  dd($ct);

  return Inertia::render('Clients/Edit', [
    'client' => [
        'id' =>  $client->id,
        'client_name' => $client->client_name,
        'address' => $client->address,
        'city' => $client->city,
        'state' => $client->state,
        'zip' => $client->zip,
    ],
    'contacts' => $contacts
  ]);
}
```

This produces a result, but I don't see the ContactType data in the result. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to trigger the query :

```
 $ct = $client->contactTypes()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load your relations using [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```php
return Inertia::render('Clients/Edit', [
    'client' => function() use($client)
   {
     return Client::where('id', $client->id)->with(['contacts', 'contactTypes'])->first();
    }
    ],
```

Comment: This is great, and I can see that the relations are populated, but how does one join the relations together on the front end? I'm think I'm failing to understand Laravel's response and how I would get say, the contact name and the contact type for client A? I would've expected to have a Clients object with an array of objects within it containing the contacts. Looking at what's returned from the server, they appear to be in separate objects. Maybe this is a new question..I dunno.

Comment: @hyphen you can try and use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) or `with(['contacts.contactType'])` so it will go trough `contacts` relation and then to `contactType` of `contacts`

Comment: @hyphen I guess you found out by now. But for the frontend it's all just a big object. So you can access something with `client.contacts[0].name` or `client.contactTypes[0].name`